# Incluir datos de un archivo PHP sin el diseño de HTML

Tags: php, html

Tengo un problema, quizá sea algo básico pero ando aprendiendo.

Tengo 2 archivos uno en donde tengo toda la estructura HTML llamado `index.php` y otro donde manejo PHP llamado `Registrar.php`.

A la hora de que se clickea el botón de tipo SUBMIT(con un form action="Registrar.php" method = "POST") en el `index.php`, me envía al otro archivo de `Registrar.php` (Cabe recalcar que en este archivo PHP tengo otro pequeño fragmento de html que lo único que hace es validar que se realizo correctamente el registro en la BD y tiene otro botón de tipo submit que es "Regresar" que lo único que realiza es regresarme al archivo index.php).

El problema esta en que como toda la lógica o Backend lo tengo en el archivo `Registrar.php`, utilice en el `index.php` un "Include" el cual extrae los elementos de el archivo de `Registrar.php`, pero tambien extrae el pequeño fragmento HTML que tiene ese mismo archivo, revolviendome todo el diseño de `index.php`.

Les dejo aquí alguno del código para que lo vean un poco mejor

index.php:

```
   <?php include("conexion.php"); include("Registrar.php"); ?>
//código html

<form action="Registrar.php" method="post" onsubmit="return checkSubmit();">
        // mas código html
   <button type="submit" class="button-43" name="boton" ><b>ENVIAR</b></button>         
                 
</form>
```

Codigo Registrar.php:

```
 //Codigo PHP Backend        
    <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
            <head>
                <meta charset="utf-8">
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
                <title>REGISTRO REALIZADO</title>
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estiloregistro.css">
            </head>
            <body>
                <form action="index.php">
                   <center>
                      <div class="bg-5">
                          <div class="glitch" data-text="GLITCH EFFECT">¡REGISTRADO CORRECTAMENTE!</div>
                          <img src="check.jpg" height="20%" width="20%" align="center">
            
                          <button type="submit" class="button-43" name="boton" ><b>REGRESAR</b></button>  
                      </div>
                   </center>
                </form>
            </body>
            </html>
```

Y el resultado es este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como pueden ver, me apontona el diseño que tengo en `Registrar.php`, nose si hay otra manera de extraer solamente lo elementos de `Registrar.php` pero sin el diseño que tengo ahi de html?

Comment: Pero porque incluye registrar en el index? si registrar solo procesa los datos. Si registrar no hace nada mas que eso no lo incluya en el index y listo. Cuando el form se envíe mostrara el botón de regresar pero no lo verá mas en el index. Es mas, en registrar no hace falta un formulario para poner un botón de "regresar". Solo pone el resultado del procesamiento de los datos un link con estilo de botón al index y listo.

Comment: Es que en el index, hay unas líneas de código donde ocupo algunos atributos de registrar. Por eso lo incluí. por que de hecho estoy haciendo algunos SELECT en donde los muestro en el apartado de Index. pero hago toda la consulta en Registrar y ya solo mando a llamar al index

Comment: Debería ordenar mejor su código. Así como incluye la conexión, puede incluir algún otro archivo que haga lo que usted necesita y al final "registrar" debe ser solo para el procesamiento del form anterior.

Answer (score 0):

usa include_once en tu index y en el form no lo envies a registrar mejor usa

```
<?php 
include_once 'conexion.php'; 
include_once 'Registrar.php'; 
?>
//código html

<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post" onsubmit="return checkSubmit();">
        // mas código html
   <button type="submit" class="button-43" name="boton" ><b>ENVIAR</b></button>         
                 
</form>
```